# How to set focus on an input element from an element inside in parent scope (AlpineJS)?

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I am using the latest version of Alpine. I need to set focus on the input searchbox as soon as it become visible. Here is my code for reference.

```html
<div x-data="{search: false}">
   <button x-on:click="search = true">Click to open search box</button>
   <div x-data="searchwidget" x-show="search">
       <input type="search" x-model="term" x-ref="searchInput" />
   </div>
</div>
```

Data handler for search input

```js
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
    Alpine.data('searchwidget', () => ({
         term: "",
    }));
});
```

I tried to put `$refs.searchInput.focus()` on button element, but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error at the button: you need to use `x-on:click="search = true"` or the shorthand syntax: `@click="search = true"`. Furthermore, Alpine.js have an official [focus plugin](https://alpinejs.dev/plugins/focus). With this plugin it is very easy to set the focus based on some condition. In your case you just need to put `x-trap="search"` to the input element, so Alpine.js will set the focus to the input element when `search` becomes `true`.

```
<input type="search" x-model="term" x-trap="search" />
```

Edit:
Without the focus plugin, you need to create a [watcher](https://alpinejs.dev/magics/watch) in the `init()` method and set focus on the input element in the [`$nextTick()`](https://alpinejs.dev/magics/nextTick) magic property:

```
<div x-data="{search: false}">
  <button @click="search = true">Click to open search box</button>
  <div x-data="searchwidget" x-show="search">
    <input type="search" x-model="term" x-ref="searchinput" />
  </div>
</div>

<script>
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
  Alpine.data('searchwidget', () => ({
    term: "",
    init() {
      this.$watch('search', (value) => {
        this.$nextTick(() => {
          if (value) {
            this.$refs.searchinput.focus()
          }
        })
      })
    }
  }));
})
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I know about plugin, I would like a direct method. And thanks for the typo reference I made with `x-click`, fixed it.

Comment: I've edited my answer for the "direct" method, but it's more verbose.

Comment: Thanks. I was close to this but not using $watch magic method. This is clean an elegant solution.